# Convert each line of a text file into a separate image using imagemagick convert

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I would like to take a text file with about 1,000 lines and create a separate png image for each line in the file using possibly ImageMagick convert. The image should be 1920x1080 with a black background and white text.  I am able to get the list (all at once) onto an image using this command:

```
convert -size 1980x1020 xc:black -font Play-Regular.ttf -pointsize 85 -fill white -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '$(cat list.txt)'" image.png
```

I also tried to create a bash file, to iterate each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
File="list.txt"
Lines=$(cat $File)
for Line in $Lines
do
convert -size 1980x1020 xc:black -font Play-Regular.ttf -pointsize 85 -fill white -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '$(cat Line)'" $line.png
done
```

I feel like I am getting closer, but my bash-fu is weak and the command threw several errors.

Comment: `Line` is already the line you want to print, so don't `cat` it, but simply `'$Line'`? This should work, but I think it's better to switch the loop from first storing the file contents in a variable to something like `while read Line; do … <"$File"`

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to process a file line-by-line and why using `for` for this purpose is problematic.

Comment: I suspect you want 1920x1080 rather than 1980x1020

Comment: *Whew* thanks for the catch, will do resizes using mogrify but, you're spot on! Gratis!

Answer (score 5):

You'd need first to convert that line in the format expected by `convert`. Here with zsh instead of bash:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
file=list.txt

typeset -Z4 n=1 # line counter 0-padded to length 4.
set -o extendedglob

while IFS= read -ru3 line; do
  # remove NUL characters if any:
  line=${line//$'\0'}
  # escape ' and \ characters with \:
  escaped_line=${line//(#m)[\'\\]/\\$MATCH}

  convert -size 1920x1080 \
          xc:black \
          -font Play-Regular.ttf \
          -pointsize 85 \
          -fill white \
          -gravity center \
          -draw "text 0,0 '$escaped_line'" line$n.png
  (( n++ ))
done 3< $file
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help! Great tutorial, a little trial and error, and my first true BASH is running and making images! Here's what worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="list.txt"
while read -r line; do
convert -size 1980x1020 xc:black -font Play-Regular.ttf -pointsize 105 -fill white -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 '$line'" $line.png
done < "$file"
```

It's so exciting when your code, actually executes!

Comment: You should quote `$line.png`. You would also get into trouble if any line has a single-quote and mangled if back-slash. Something like `escaped_line=${line//\\/\\\\}; escaped_line=${line//\'/\\\'}`

Comment: … and that should obviously be: `escaped_line=${line//\\/\\\\}; escaped_line=${escaped_line//\'/\\\'}` :P